# Android: How to call a function on click of an invisible button?

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have an image on my screen and want the user to touch a specific region of the image. I have placed an `invisible` button on top of the region I want the user to click and set an `onClickListener` on the same.

From what I read, `INVISIBLE` buttons still acquire the space they are at, unlike `GONE` buttons.

However, the `onClick` method is not invoked if I click the region. Is there a fact I am missing or an alternate way to achieve this?

```java
public class InteractiveFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, OnClickableAreaClickedListener {

    private Button btnEye;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interactive, container, false);
        btnEye = view.findViewById(R.id.btnEye);
        btnEye.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEye.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("method invoked");
    }
]
```

Comment: take a look at : https://github.com/Lukle/ClickableAreasImages

Comment: yea it still acquires space, but you have to write your logic if that space is clicked. take a look at that library mentioned above

Comment: @Sam I have written my logic for when it is clicked. That is how I know that my onClick method is not being invoked.

Comment: I mean.. that invisiblebutton.setOnClickListener() will not work, if that is your logic.. since you haven't posted any code

Comment: @Sam. added code as well

Comment: as i said, invisiblebutton on click listener won't work. Try this instead.. btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and btn.setbackgroundcolor(Color.Transparent); and make sure your button have specific width and not wrap_content. you can adjust as per the image.. (cause i am assuming there won't be any text on button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should know the android event dispatch mechanism. we can see 
 it in the `ViewGrouop` `dispatchOnTouchEvent` method source code.

here is the core code:

```
//child is the view
if (!child.canReceivePointerEvents()|| !isTransformedTouchPointInView(x, y, child, null)) {
        ev.setTargetAccessibilityFocus(false);
         continue;
     }

// the  canReceivePointerEvents method in view
protected boolean canReceivePointerEvents() {
       return (mViewFlags & VISIBILITY_MASK) == VISIBLE || getAnimation() != null;
    }
```

we can get when the view is `INVISBLE`, it **can not receive the event**, the parent don't dispatch event to it.

so if you want to respond to click event, you have to set it `VISIBLE`, set the button background `transparent`.

```
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn.setbackgroundcolor(Color.Transparent);
```

Comment: I did assume that a invisible view can take click event until I have caught up your answer. Very useful!!

Answer (score 2):

Set the background to transparent and added a finite size to the button. Courtesy @Sam

Used the following `xml` config for the button

```xml
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnEye"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
tools:visibility="visible" />
```